# How to send POST request with query params for image field in django tests

Tags: django, django-testing

I have `test.py`

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.urls import reverse

class PostImageTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.product = Product.objects.create(...)
        self.sampleImage = SimpleUploadedFile("test_image.jpg", b"binary data", content_type="image/jpeg")

    def test_with_valid_data(self) -> None:
        data = { "image":self.sampleImage, "is_featured":true }
        response = client.post(reverse('images'), data, format='multipart')
```

I want to pass query params like **`images?product=id`** to the `client.post()` method. Also i'm not getting as to how to encode the image and send a POST request.

When i tried like this

```
response = client.post(reverse('images'), {'product' : self.product.id}, data=data, format='multipart')
```

It gives me this error

`TypeError: Client.post() got multiple values for argument 'data'`

Comment: How is your request look alike in your dev tools?

Comment: `{{baseUrl}}/images?product=1` . This is the request i'm sending via postman where it works. Also i'm selecting an image via the `form-data` option in postman to hit the request

Comment: What is the payload?

Comment: payload = { "image" : some_image, "is_featured" : true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image as img

def get_url(self, paramKey=None, paramValue=None):
    url = reverse('images') + f"?{paramKey}={paramValue}"
    return url

def create_valid_image(self):
    image_file = BytesIO()
    image = img.new('RGBA', size=(50, 50), color=(155, 0, 0))
    image.save(image_file, 'png')
    image_file.name = 'test_image.png'
    image_file.seek(0)
    return image_file

def test_with_valid_data(self) -> None:
    self.myImage = self.create_valid_image()
    expectedStatusCode = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

    url = self.get_url('product', self.product.id)
    data = { 'image' : self.myImage, 'is_featured' : True }
    response = client.post(url, data)
    receivedStatusCode = response.status_code

    self.assertEqual(receivedStatusCode, expectedStatusCode)
```

So, it looks like if we pass query_params in client.post(), it will consider it as request data. So we have to concatenate the query_params to the original url.

Can further go through this [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post)